# Net Sql AZMan authentication and authorization

Tags: c#, authentication, unauthorized, azman, netsqlazman

I am Using Net Sql AZMan to authentication and authorization in my application and i defined a Task for Update and I have a operation for updating Order's Information.
Now i want to authorization  this :
All the users can Update a order's information when they are in Editor Role but they can't Update the order's information when Order's Id is ('X' for example),
when the Order's Id is ('X' for example) only the user's in Admin Role can Update the order's information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement a long time ago and tried NetSqlAzman for it.  Unfortunately, NetSqlAzMan does not support this authorization scheme. They have a feature that they call attributes that has many design limitations that make it unusable.

Here is part of my discussion with the NetSqlAzMan author on codeplex regarding a limitation:
http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/discussions/282501

I suggest that you create a table to serve as an ACL and then implement the authorization logic yourself.